# What is this kind of toggle switch nut called?

Tags: toggle-switch

Toggle switches are frequently attached to a mounting surface with a nut that has two indentations on opposite sides.

- What is this kind of nut called?
- What kind of tool is good for tightening and loosening this fastener?

I usually use needle nose pliers.  They work, but sometimes mar the fastener.

[image]

Comment: Nice Taranis, I just got mine, do you need to loosen the two switches to open the radio? TIA

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've always known them as slot or slotted nuts (a type of castellated nut) although I did come across a reference to switch nuts, which makes sense if they are used to fasten switches.

[image]

Comment: +1 nice find on the slotted nut wrenches, I remember having seen those as well now you mention the name. They'll be better than the circlip pliers if the OP can find the right size OK.

Comment: @PeterJ Yes, its a blast from the past. ;)

Answer (score 4):

There are probably a few names but I've often heard them referred to as dress nuts. A search on Digikey using that term shows plenty of fairly similar nuts although they don't appear to have any with the slot at the top:

http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?x=0&y=0&lang=en&site=us&KeyWords=dress+nut

I'm not sure if specialised tools are available but a pair of circlip pliers from your local hardware store might do the job, they are available in a wide variety of styles and sizes so take the switch along with you to find one that suits. Most have round prongs which you could remove to make things easier.

[image: Circlip pliers]